# Подключить SFML в VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Нужно подключить SFML для работы в VS Code на Windows. Никакой адекватной информации не нашел, разве что для Linux. Может кто знает как это сделать?

Comment: Опишите ваш вопрос подробнее, какой компилятор вы используете, какую систему сборки и т.д. Тогда на ваш вопрос возможно ответят.

Comment: [vcpkg](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=vs-2019)